# a query that sum the count of a row from multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, common-table-expression

I have to write a query that sum the count of a row from multiple columns

My code is like this, but total doesn't work:

```
WITH 
NextPreviousItemAndTotal
AS
(
    SELECT LAG(Datetype, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY Fname ORDER BY Datetype ASC) AS PreviousItemDate,
            LAG(Fcount,1) OVER(PARTITION BY Fname ORDER BY Datetype) AS  PreviousItemCount,
            CurrentItemDate, CurrentItemCount,
            LEAD(Datetype, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY Fname ORDER BY Datetype ASC) AS NextItemDate, 
            LEAD(Fcount,1) OVER(PARTITION BY Fname ORDER BY Datetype) AS NextItemCount,
            SUM(Fcount) OVER(PARTITION BY Fname ORDER BY Datetype ) AS Total
    FROM FoodSara_tbl 
)
SELECT PreviousItemDate, PreviousItemCount, CurrentItemDate, CurrentItemCount,CurrentItemCount,NextItemCount, Total
FROM NextPreviousItemAndTotal
```

input:

```
|PreviousItemDate|PreviousItemCount|CurrentItemDate|CurrentItemCount|NextItemDate|NextItemCount|
 |----------------|-----------------|---------------|----------------|------------|-------------|
 |   Null         |    Null         |   2019/10/10  |      10        |2019/10/12  |  2          |
 |   2019/10/10   |     10          |2019/10/12     |    2           |2020/01/20  |  12         |
 |  2019/10/12    |  12             |2020/01/20     |   12           |Null        |  Null       |
```

output:

```
|PreviousItemDate|PreviousItemCount|CurrentItemDate|CurrentItemCount|NextItemDate|NextItemCount|Total|
 |----------------|-----------------|---------------|----------------|------------|-------------|-----|
 |   Null         |    Null         |   2019/10/10  |      10        |2019/10/12  |  2          |12   |
 |   2019/10/10   |     10          |2019/10/12     |    2           |2020/01/20  |  12         |24   |
 |  2019/10/12    |  12             |2020/01/20     |   8            |Null        |  Null       |20   |
```

Comment: And what do you want the value to be?  What logic defines `total`?  Your query also references many columns that are not part of the `input`, which is a bit confusing.

Comment: yea, u were right, i edited that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `coalesce` as follows:

```
Coalesce(PreviousItemCount,0) 
+ Coalesce(currentItemCount,0)
+ Coalesce(nextItemCount,0) as total
```

Answer (score 0):

I change a little bit name of the columns but it will work

```
WITH 
NextPreviousItemAndTotal
AS
(
    SELECT LAG(Datetype, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY Fname ORDER BY Datetype ASC) AS PreviousItemDate,
            LAG(Fregion,1) OVER(PARTITION BY Fname ORDER BY Datetype) AS PreviousRegion,
            LAG(Fcount,1) OVER(PARTITION BY Fname ORDER BY Datetype) AS PreviousCount,
            Datetype, Fregion, Fname, Fcount,
            LEAD(Datetype, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY Fname ORDER BY Datetype ASC) AS NextItemDate, 
            LEAD(Fregion,1) OVER(PARTITION BY Fname ORDER BY Datetype) AS NextItemRegion,
            LEAD(Fcount,1) OVER(PARTITION BY Fname ORDER BY Datetype) AS NextCount
            
    FROM FoodSara_tbl 
)
SELECT PreviousItemDate, PreviousRegion,PreviousCount, Datetype, Fregion, Fname, Fcount, NextItemDate, NextItemRegion,NextCount, Coalesce(PreviousCount,0) + Coalesce(Fcount,0)+ Coalesce(NextCount,0)AS Total
FROM NextPreviousItemAndTotal
```